# Does the leather strap often depicted on a Pith helmets serve a purpose, or is it purely cosmetic?

Tags: uniform, fashion

Pith Helmet are often depicted with a dark leather strap across the front (See picture).

Does this strap serve a functional purpose: For example, is it a chin strap that has been hooked up to keep it out of the wearer's face. Or is it a purely decorative item included for cosmetic purposes?

[image]

Are there any historic or contemporary texts that describe it's evolution or use, or what the etiquette was regarding it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130810/discussion-on-question-by-aaargh-zombies-does-the-leather-strap-often-depicted-o).

Comment: How do I do the above?

Answer (score 6):

It's a chinstrap. It was used mainly for decorative purposes, but also to keep the helmet on the head when riding horses or in strong winds.

I never wore a pith helmet, but a peaked cap. The chinstrap served a similar *(and almost exclusively decorative)* purpose. I served in the army; in the navy, the chinstrap is used. They encounter stronger winds than we do in a field or forest.

Answer (score 0):

It's a chinstrap. [image]
meant to hold in combative use. But as pith helmet gave rise to modern helmets, the strap became more decoration than useful. The helmet is a modern variation of the traditional Salakot, a wide brim hat meant to wick away moisture and keep sun out of workers face.